# How can dimethyl maleate be converted to dimethyl fumarate using piperidine?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: Reaction scheme]

To move from the Z isomer to the E isomer, the  π bond will need to break to allow free rotation. Once the bond is broken, I think that forming the trans (E) alkene will be more stable as it has less steric hindrance.

I think you could add the piperidine to the C=C bond to give some sort of amine but I do not know how that group could be removed to give the alkene again.

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE! Your question will likely be considered as homework and be voted down. You need to make some effort to answer the question yourself. Take a look here about [homework policy](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange).

Comment: @Viraj How stable do you think the addition product is?